# Uso de gsub, remplazar caracteres no funciona

Tags: r

Estoy intentado reemplazar con la función `gsub` dentro de una columna llamada "MSZoning", las celdas que contengan la palabra "C(all)", reemplazándola sólo por "C"

Escribo el código: `datos$MSZoning = gsub("C(all)","C", datos$MSZoning)` pero no se aplica ningún cambio, las celdas que debían cambiar de nombre siguen igual

¿Cómo puedo cambiarlas correctamente? Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Ocurre que `gsub` recibe un patrón de [expresiones regulares](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expresi%C3%B3n_regular) y los paréntesis en particular son patrones especiales que indican que se quiere capturar lo que hay dentro de los mismos. Entonces al hacer esto:

```
cadena <- "C(all) de ejemplo"
gsub("C(all)","C", cadena)
C(all) de ejemplo"
```

no funciona como lo esperas, es necesario "escapar" los paréntesis para indicar que no se trata de los caracteres de control sino de los literales, para esto en R usamos la doble barra:

```
cadena <- "C(all) de ejemplo"
gsub("C\\(all\\)","C", cadena)
[1] "C de ejemplo"
```